# Checkboxes remember selection - ASP NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I`m making sort of a quiz with games' photos using ASP.NET MVC 4. Each page contains question, random image and randomly choosen answers. Submitting the answer redirects back to HomeController, where next question is being randomly choosen.

The problem is as followed: in first question i can have either first checkbox checked (if Answer is set to Choices[0]), or none of them checked. I choose the first answer, submit it and the choice is "remembered" in next question (the same answer is checked by default, if exist), although the Answer property is equal to null.

First question (everything is ok, I am choosing the right answer):
[image: first image]

Second question (previous answer is still checked, and I don't know why)
[image: second image]

Thanks in advance for explaining me this

---- EDIT ----

My Controllers:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            QuestionViewModel vm = PrepareQuestion();

            return View(vm);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(QuestionViewModel previousVm)
        {
            QuestionViewModel vm = PrepareQuestion();

            vm.PreviousCorrectAnswer = previousVm.CorrectAnswer;
            vm.PreviousAnswer = previousVm.Answer;

            return View(vm);
        }
```

`PrepareQuestion` method deserializes galleries from XML, choose one randomly and return as a viewModel.

In a view, I render image (path is in viewmodel), list of answers using `@Html.RadioButtonFor( m => m.Answer)` and submit button

Comment: There's something about your binding that's persisting the value of the previously selected answer. The screenshots don't help. The concise and relevant pieces of code is what's needed to solve this.

Comment: Maybe it's your webbrowser that remembers the values for a specific input name.

Comment: @Marek, so the `PrepareQuestion` method is returning an object that has an answer selected.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud exactly not, I do `Answer = null;` there